# How do you remove plugin edit option?

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, editor

I would like to remove the edit option for all plugins on a wordpress site. Is there a hook/filter for doing this? It would be preferred to do it from the theme's functions file, rather than try to disable it within each plugin. Ideally, it could be removed for users without admin privileges, but that is a secondary  concern.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to your WordPress installs *wp-config.php*

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true);
```

Comment: That did it! Awesome. However, due to the version control setup we have, I would still prefer to do it within the theme functions. And the good news is, you can put this code there instead, and it still works! Merci!

Comment: Yup, you can set wordpress constants elsewhere as well. *wp-config.php* simply is the default location where you'd do so. If within the theme seems to be a better fit for your case, I don't see why you shouldn't set it there. You can wrap it in conditionals (user role) there as well.

Comment: Can I do this for one particular plugin...